# Count entries for current month and certain text matches

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet with a date column, a category column and two columns for calculations. The calculation is to count the entries for the current month if category matches.

I have tried countif formula, however am unable to count the entries for current month.

Table example:

[image]

Comment: Hi KKW1975, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to count on multiple criteria so make sure you are using COUNTIFS not COUNTIF.

We can make this formula dynamic by adding in a few reference cells to get the start of the month and the end of the month to make it easier to count. In a cell that is not being used and will not get in the way of the table let's type this start date formula:

=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1

Here's what this formula is doing:

1. TODAY() is getting today's date so this will update every time you open the workbook on a new day.
2. EOMONTH(TODAY,-1) is using today's date as a starting point and then getting the last day of the month. Then it is subtracting 1 month and getting the last day of that month.
3. +1 is adding one day to the last day of the previous month which will always be the first day of the current month

Next let's create a similar formula to get the last day of the current month.
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)

This is basically doing the same thing as step in the previous step except we aren't moving forward or backwards any months.

Now that we have our Start Date & End Dates we can calculate whether our Date in the date column is within the current month time frame by using the following COUNTIFS formula:

=COUNTIFS(A2,">="&$G$1,A2,"<="&$G$2,B2,"yes")

When using any aggregate function such as SUMIF,COUNTIF, AVERAGEIF and using >,< operators you have to wrap the operator in quotation marks. You also have to use the & after the quotations before referencing the cell or number of which you are comparing to.

Here is the final view:

[image]